# Characters for ben1 ben1 meaning 围巾 or 围嘴?

Tags: characters

There is a word in Southern Mandarin dialects pronounced `ben1 ben1` meaning 围巾 or 围嘴.

Dictionary entries usually just give a:

> □ □

meaning that there is no known character for writing this word.

It is more than possible that there does, though, exist characters that could be used to write this word.

Any ideas what it might be?

Comment: 衯衯 could also be a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is just a guess**:

围巾 is a scarf; 围嘴 is a bib, also known as 圍兜.

围巾 and 围嘴/圍兜 are two different things.

But the pronunciation /ben1/ gave us a clue. You are probably thinking of 'bib'

[Bib](https://www.google.ca/search?q=bib&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ1K3XyoDVAhUD3IMKHcDbAg4Q_AUICigB&biw=1361&bih=659)  ( [圍兜](https://www.google.ca/search?q=bib&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ1K3XyoDVAhUD3IMKHcDbAg4Q_AUICigB&biw=1361&bih=659#tbm=isch&q=%E5%9C%8D%E5%85%9C) )

'Bib' sounded like 'ben1' in Mandarin. What you are looking for is probably a loaned word for 'bib'

If it is a loaned word, the character itself might have nothing to do with the actual item.

The only character that is pronounced as/ben1/  in Mandarin is 奔 /ben1/; /ben4/

It is just my guess, but to indicated  this loaned word  奔 is related to 'cloth' a 巾 radical might be added to 奔 and make it looked like this:

[image: bib-loaned word]

or this:

[image]

user3306356 wrote:

> *衯衯 could also be a possibility.*

Yes, most loaned words are just sounded like the original foreign words. It could be some other similar sounding words in this case.

More importantly, I have no proof that it is actually a loaned word. We need someone who know the history of this item to give a definite answer.

**Edit:**

> In Cantonese, 'bib' is called [口水肩](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/44879/)--  often shortened to just '肩' /gin1/ , which is the only single character that can mean 'bib' in Chinese (Cantonese).
>
> '肩肩' would be a baby talk.
>
> However, it is pronounced /jian1/ in Mandarin

Answer (score 2):

I would go for one of the following words:

衯衯: 衣長的樣子。《文選．司馬相如．子虛賦》：「衯衯裶裶，揚袘戍削。」

繃繃：《前漢·宣帝紀》曾孫雖在襁緥。《註》師古曰：襁卽今之小兒繃也。